# Minifiy a PHP code that uses the sort() function

Tags: php, minify

I have this function, which I am trying to put it on one line, but I cannot figure out how could i implement sort() in same line.

```
# Mediana x̃    de un conjunto de elementos ($e)
Mediana($e=array()){    
  sort($e); 
  return (count($e)!=0)?((count($e)%2==0)?(($e[(count($e)/2)]+$e[((count($e)/2)+1)])/2):$e[((count($e)/2)+1)]):0;
}
```

I don't like (esthetically talking) the dirty way:

```
sort($e); return (count($e)!=0)?((count($e)%2==0)?(($e[(count($e)/2)]+$e[((count($e)/2)+1)])/2):$e[((count($e)/2)+1)]):0;
```

I will be thankful if someone could give me some tips about it.
Tnx.

Comment: Is there any reason to put it on one line?

Comment: No, just i was minifiying, and i got a OCD attack when i saw sort(), so lonely in his own line

Comment: There is a point at which reduced code becomes difficult to understand and maintain.  Your `return` code is already confusing and can become a big problem with errors as it just seems to be a mess of conditions.

Comment: Indeed, but not it's what i'm talking about.
I'm not around the legibility of this function i'm just minifiying for refreshing porpuses, but when i have some operational not returned function, it seems impossible to avoid using in his own line (not as returned function as count())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include `sort()` to the conditions thus method returns boolean value and once sorted array stays sorted in this case.

```
function Mediana($e = array())
{
    return (count($e) != 0 && sort($e)) ? ((count($e) % 2 == 0) ? (($e[(count($e) / 2)] + $e[((count($e) / 2) + 1)]) / 2) : $e[((count($e) / 2) + 1)]) : 0;
}
```

or

```
function Mediana($e = array())
{
    return (sort($e) && count($e) != 0) ? ((count($e) % 2 == 0) ? (($e[(count($e) / 2)] + $e[((count($e) / 2) + 1)]) / 2) : $e[((count($e) / 2) + 1)]) : 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanx dude, i forgot completly it can be executed on if statement.
You rock

Comment: You can even shorten this function using arrow functions in PHP 7.4 https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arrow.php